# Implement QMR-DT model using PYMC?

Tags: pymc

I am trying to implement a QMR-DT model ([link here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/jair/pub/volume10/jaakkola99a-html/node2.html#fqmr)) using PyMC.

I set up a simple model using the code below.

```
qmr-dt model
import pylab as pl
import pymc 

# F0 and F1 are the findings, and D1, D2, D3 are the diseases.

F0_obs = [0.]
F1_obs = [1.]

N = len(F0_obs)

D1 = pymc.Bernoulli('Diagnosis_1', 0.80, value=pl.ones(N))
D2 = pymc.Bernoulli('Diagnosis_2', 0.50, value=pl.ones(N))
D3 = pymc.Bernoulli('Diagnosis_3', 0.80, value=pl.ones(N))

# This represents the following CPT
# D2, D1: (False, False = 0.01), (False, True = 0.5), (True, False = 0.99), (True, True = 0.99)
p_F0 = pymc.Lambda('p_Finding_0', lambda D1=D1, D2=D2:
            pl.where(D2, pl.where(D1, 0.99, 0.99), pl.where(D1, 0.5, 0.01)),
            doc='Pr[F0|D1,D2]')

# D3, D2: (False, False = 0.01), (False, True = 0.6), (True, False = 0.7), (True, True = 0.99)
p_F1 = pymc.Lambda('p_Finding_1', lambda D1=D1, D3=D3:
            pl.where(D3, pl.where(D1, 0.99, 0.7), pl.where(D1, 0.6, 0.01)),
            doc='Pr[F1|D1,D3]')

F0 = pymc.Bernoulli('Finding_0', p_F0, value=F0_obs, observed=True)
F1 = pymc.Bernoulli('Finding_1', p_F1, value=F1_obs)
```

This results in the graphical model shown below.

[QMR-DT Model](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o4335a868v6y8u6/graph.png)

My questions are:

1. What is the best way of specifying conditional probability tables when the number of disease and finding nodes is larger - on the order of 15 - 20? The pl.where approach doesn't scale too well. Am I missing something in the documentation that enables a simpler/scalable specification?
2. Is initialization of unobserved variables required? I have seen conflicting notes on this point on the web.